# JSON.stringify options

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm returning an SQL query and using JSON.stringify to store the query in a JSON file.

Here is my code:

```
fs.writeFileSync('data/csv/file.json', JSON.stringify(results));
```

Which is giving me the following output when saved to file:

```
[{"":4.55},{"":114}]
```

I'm wanting to instead output the following:

```
[4.55, 114]
```

Is there a way to do this with JSON.stringify?

**UPDATE**

As per the answer from @cars10

The following did the trick:

```
JSON.stringify(results.map(a=>a['']))
```

Comment: How are you getting `results`? Those empty-string keys seem very unorthodox.

Comment: Where does 'results' come from, and what is its value?

Comment: That has nothing to do with JSON. You need to mutate your input object. Odds are pretty good that you want to fix the underlying bug that is producing these objects in the first place though.

Comment: @meagar to be fair, there _is_ a current behavior and desired behavior. I guess the main issue is that there's not enough information to reproduce `results`, which categorizes this as an XY problem.

Comment: Well, we have all the necessary information in the JSONised form of `result`: it is an array with two objects? And yes, JSON.stringify can do this conversion. I don't understand why this question was closed.

Comment: @trincot the problem is this is an XY problem, and it would be much more helpful to see what's _creating_ `results` and solve _that_ rather than fixing an issue further along caused by bad code in the first place.

Comment: I don't think there is much XY about it: the SQL result set probably returns column name + value as key/value pair, one object per row, and apparently the SQL `select` clause has one, non-aliased expression, which seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
JSON.stringify(Object.values(results))
```

instead.

**Edit:** This is not yet the correct solution since it only works for input like `{"":4.55, " ":114}`.

Looking a bit closer at your example, you will have to do:

```
JSON.stringify(results.map(a=>a['']))
```

`results=[{"":4.55},{"":114}]` then turns into `"[ 4.55, 114 ]"`.

`results` seems to be an array with a collection of objects inside. From each object you want the property `""` placed into the output array.

Comment: Good advice, just to add a note here, The [compatibility for `Object.values()`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-Object_static_methods_a_href=_https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values_Object.values_/a_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;) in Node.js is >= 6.5 < 7.0 behind the `--harmony` flag, and >= 7.0

Comment: Yeah, quite right, but the edited solution works without `Object.value()`, since `results` appears to be an array after all ;-)

Comment: Thanks!! This worked perfectly!